# How does one open a pdf in a new tab using C# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i can read the pdf and open it in the current tab however everything i have tried to open the pdf in a new tab is not working.  I added javascript as seen in the commented out sections and yet it always opens in the same tab.  Is it something i am missing or am i overthinking it

```
protected void bttnpdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = null;
    fileName = "testPdf1.pdf";

    if (fileName != null)
    {
        string path = @"c:\TestCode\TestPdfs\" + fileName;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            WebClient User = new WebClient();
            Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(path);
            if (FileBuffer != null)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('" + FileBuffer + "');", true);
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
            //string script = string.Format("window.open('{0}','_blank');", FileBuffer);
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
            //                      "ServerControlScript", script, true);
            //bttnpdf.SetClientScript(string.Format("window.open('{0}','_blank');", FileBuffer), false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't open a new browser tab from your server-side C# code. You would need to have the `bttnpdf` element that triggers this method to open the new window via HTML or JS.

Comment: And even then you cannot be sure it opens in a tab, i always download pdf's not show them in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the target attribute of the link to "_blank" in your front-end code (Razor view). It'll open the link in a new window.

Comment: i dont have the reputation to give you an upvote but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write the action in a separate ashx page to get the result, then just pass from the client side to the ashx page

Only in place

```
Response
```

Use with

```
context.Response
```