# How can I open a PDF file in ASP.NET in a new tab after retrieving it from a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working on a ASP.NET Webforms app and I need to retrieve some PDF files stored as `Blob` on a SQL Server database. So far, I can see from the app the files that are on the table, but I cannot open them from a button click. The server-side code to read the `byte[] array` is this:

```
protected void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<BinaryServer> binaryFiles = bs.BinariesServer.GetBinariesServer(Token);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=Test.pdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(binaryFiles[0].Blob);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Interestingly though, when debugging the above code it executes fine, but the event `Application_Error()` in `Global.asax.cs` is raised, and no file is opened.

I've checked the following solutions, but none of them has been useful.

- [ASP.NET Core How to open PDF in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805338/asp-net-core-how-to-open-pdf-in-a-new-tab)
- [How To Open PDF Files In New Tab In Browser Using GridView Row Command In ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080505/how-to-open-pdf-files-in-new-tab-in-browser-using-gridview-row-command-in-asp-ne)
- [How does one open a pdf in a new tab using C# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78022174/how-does-one-open-a-pdf-in-a-new-tab-using-c-sharp-asp-net)

---

In fact, what I really want to do is list the files (not just PDF but also Excel, txt and others) in a `ListView` with a button each to download, but for the PDF case I'd prefer to open it in a new tab instead of directly downloading.

Comment: In your question you'd need to included details about the error message you're getting.

Comment: Well, I can't find the error because the code doesn't raise an exception, but on the client side I do get the exception that the received message from the client could not be analyzed.

Comment: `SuppressContent = true;` is basically supressing the output. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.suppresscontent?view=netframework-4.8.1 Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so say we have this markup - a grid view:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridFiles" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
        CssClass="table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="GridFiles_RowDataBound"
        DataKeyNames="ID"
        >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpLoaded" HeaderText="UpLoaded" ItemStyle-Width="175" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgPreview" runat="server" Height="80" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDownLoad"
                        runat="server" CssClass="btn myshadow"
                        OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click" style="margin-top:20px" > 
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete"
                        runat="server" CssClass="btn myshadow" style="margin-top:20px"
                        OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"> 
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


    <script>

        function newtab() {
            var sURL = "ShowPdf.aspx"
            window.open(sURL, '_blank');
        }
    </script>
```

And note the button click - I used a LinkButton since I wanted a "icon", but a simple standard asp.net button would also work.

So, if the file is not a pdf, then we download, or we open to the other page.

So, the button click event looks like this:

```
    protected void cmdDownLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton myBut = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)myBut.NamingContainer; // get current grid row
        int PK = (int)GridFiles.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblFiles WHERE ID = @ID");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK;

        DataTable dt = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        string strFile = dt.Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString();

        if (Path.GetExtension(strFile).ToUpper() == ".PDF")
        {
            // This is a pdf, so setup pk for display page
            Session["PK"] = PK;
            string sJava = "newtab();";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myjump", sJava, true);
        }
        else
        {
            string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFile);
            byte[] FileData = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["FileB"];

            Response.ContentType = sMineType;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile);
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileData);
            Response.End();    
        }
    }
```

So, if a pdf, then we set the PK value, and call the JavaScript routine to jump to the new page on a new tab.

The new page then has this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int PK = (int)Session["PK"];
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblFiles WHERE ID = @ID");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK;

        DataTable dt = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        string strFile = dt.Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString();
        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFile);

        byte[] FileData = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["FileB"];

        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename={strFile}");
        Response.BinaryWrite(FileData);
        Response.End();

    }
```

The result is thus this:

[image]

So, it not that you pull the binary file and THEN try to display on a new page.

You check the file type, and if it is a PDF, then  you save the database PK value into session, and then run some JavaScript to open the new page in a new tab, and that page then loads/displays the pdf as per above.

Comment: Thanks for your solution; I had to do some changes (like deleting the `OnRowDataBound` event or deleting the preview), but now it's working for what I needed. One more question: When the `OnUploadComplete` event fires on the server, some variables are empty, like a `BootstrapGridView` that I have on the same page, or the hidden fields. Any ideas why it might be so?

Comment: Since the AjaxFileUpLoad does NOT post back, then all of the controls etc. are sitting on the users desktop. thus, in the 3 events (start, uploadComplete, and AllComplate) can't use any control from the existing form. That's why I suggested the client side "click button" code, since it means you DO HAVE a post back after everything is done. So, without a postback, then those 3 upload events can't see, use or modify controls on the page since no post-back has occurred. This is expected when no post back has occurred. So, code behind without a post back can't see nor use controls on the page.

Comment: So, the AjaxFileUpLoad has provisions for calling a client side JS routine. So, I use the last "all upload complete", and have a clinet side JS routine do this:  $("#btnDone").click().   So this then clicks a final button, and we have a post back after all uploading is done, and you now have a button code stub that runs server side code after uploading is done.

Comment: I tried adding the button on the same modal as the `ajaxToolkit`, I also added the client-side click event, but if I change the upload event to uploadAll, then I can no longer retrieve the files, and if I leave the uploadComplete event, the Postback happens after it and the button event after both.

Comment: I do this all the time. You can't have a post-back for the 1st 2 events (UpLoad start, and Upload complete). But you most certainly can trigger a post back for the 3rd event, and that's when all of the files been uploaded anyway (UpLoadComplte all). And in 3rd event you can't get at the files(s) list anyway with all uploading has occurred. So you can't have a post back occur for the 1st 2 upload events (start, and UpLoadComplete). But, for the 3rd event (All complete), then it should not be an issue. Of course that final button click will collapse the modal dialog. So, it depends on your goal

Comment: However, if you really need a button click and post-back AND ALSO the modal dialog to stay open? then you can place the div inside of a update panel. I should also point out that this discussion pertains to the previous upload code posted, not this post/question in which the goal was to launch/show a new tab. So, while you can keep the dialog popup open, you STILL cannot have a post back for the 2 upload events, only the 3rd event.

Comment: Thanks for your answers; I solved it yesterday evening.